# Which of the following is bigger: $\int_{0}^{\pi\over 2}\sin^2(x)$ or $\int_{0}^{\pi\over 2}\sin^{10}(x)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Which of the following is bigger: $\int_{0}^{\pi\over 2}\sin^2(x)dx$ or $\int_{0}^{\pi\over 2}\sin^{10}(x)dx$?

I got that $\int_{0}^{\pi\over 2}\sin^2(x)dx={\pi\over 4}$. Then I have realized that I can't possibly find $\int \sin^{10}(x)dx$ as it is way too tedious and potentially full of mistakes. I know that if $f,g\in [a,b]\to \Bbb{R}$ are integrable and that if $f\ge g$ so $\int_{a}^{b}f\ge \int_{a}^{b}g$. Can I simply apply it here? It can't be so easy. Am I missing something here? I would appreciate your observation.

Comment: Which is bigger, $\sin^2(x)$ or $\sin^{10}(x)$?

Comment: You do have to do a tiny bit of work to _show_ that $f \geq g$. (That is, you need the answer to the previous comment.) But yes, it really is that easy.

Comment: Yes you can apply it here. Note that $\sin{x} \in (0,1)$.

Comment: I guess it depends on the domain. For $0<x<{\pi\over 2}$, since $\sin x\in [0,1]$ then $....<\sin^3{(x)}<\sin^2(x)<sin(x)$? 
Is it direct or something I should prove in my exercise?

Comment: As an aside, see [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $\forall x \in \Bbb{R} $: $\sin x \in [-1,1]$, you can say that 
$ \sin^{2} x \ge \sin^{4} x \ge \sin^{6} x \ge \sin^{8} x \ge \sin^{10} x \ge ...$

$ \sin^{2} x$ and $\sin^{10} x $ are both contineous so they are both integrable.

So you can apply you rule.

Comment: With the argument in $(0,\pi/2)$, odd exponents do as well.

Comment: Pretty elegant it is to prove a stronger claim. Thank you.

Comment: How can you rule out equality of the integrals?

Comment: you mean why $\int_{0}^{\pi\over 2}\sin^2(x)dx$ > $\int_{0}^{\pi\over 2}\sin^{10}(x)dx$ and not $\int_{0}^{\pi\over 2}\sin^2(x)dx  \ge\int_{0}^{\pi\over 2}\sin^{10}(x)dx$?

Comment: @RobbeMotmans yes.

Comment: because for $x \in ]0,\pi/2[$, $\sin^2(x) > \sin^{10}(x)$

Answer (score 2):

using the facts that $$  0 < y < 1 \implies 0 < y^{10} < y^2 < 1 \text{ and } 0 < \sin x < 1$$ you can conclude $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{10} \, dx < \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2} \, dx .$$